# Issues Joining Multiple Tables in Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, join, inner-join

Currently I have a select query that joins many tables together and looks something like this:

```
SELECT Phone.ID, User.ID, Center.ID, UDL.ID, Bill_Cycles.[Bill Date], Accounts.ID
FROM tbl_Accounts INNER JOIN (((((Phone 
  INNER JOIN tbl_IMPORT 
   ON Phone.[Wireless Number] = tbl_IMPORT.[Wireless Number])
 INNER JOIN User
   ON tbl_IMPORT.[User Name] = User.[User Name]) 
 INNER JOIN Center
   ON tbl_IMPORT.[ Center Name] = Center.[ Center]) 
 INNER JOIN UDL
   ON tbl_IMPORT.[UDL] = UDL.[UDL])
 INNER JOIN Bill_Cycles 
  ON tbl_IMPORT.[Bill Date] = Bill_Cycles.[Bill Date])
 INNER JOIN Accounts
  ON Accounts.[Account Number] = tbl_IMPORT.[Account]
```

When I run this query it works perfectly, but when I try to add a table that can't be joined with the `tbl_Import` table, it just returns a blank table. What I mean is the tables I have now all have a corresponding category in `tbl IMPORT` that I can join with. The New tables I want to join, don't have anything in the `tbl_IMPORT` that I can connect it to. Is there away to connect the above statement with the following: `INNER JOIN Inventory ON Inventory.[ID]=Device.[ID]`. As I mentioned earlier, adding this line to the end of my select statement returns blank results.

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to connect two completely unrelated tables. Is that the case or am I misreading?

Comment: Somewhat, yes. The only relatable category that is shared between `tbl_IMPORT, Inventory, and Device` are the Bill Dates. `tbl_IMPORT` and `Inventory` should both have the same bill dates.

Comment: Tha doesn't sound like that would be unique enough to do what you want, but maybe. In which case you would go have to join Inventory first to tbl_IMPORT and then join in Device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments above it seems as if you have to first join to Inventory on [Bill Date] and then to Device.

```
INNER JOIN Inventory ON tbl_IMPORT.[Bill Date] = Inventory.[Bill Date]
INNER JOIN Device ON Inventory.[ID]=Device.[ID]
```

On the surface that seems like an unusual data model, but could be. If that not enough, you maybe want to either:

a) Adjust the question to show a much simpler example that demonstrate the difficulty, or
b) Add the relevant table definitions so we can get a better perspective.

Comment: Well I would test this, but for some reason I'm getting a syntax error on the `INNER` piece of the `INNER JOIN` that joins inventory on tbl_IMPORT. Says ` Syntax Error in From Clause`

Comment: There was a space between Inventory and .[Bill Date]. That may have been it.